# Arduino to PC secure bluetooth connection

Tags: security, arduino, iot, arduino-ide

I'm using an Arduino Uno to build a smoke detection system, which works. Since I have to do an IoT project, I have to establish a secure connection with a (for example) Web server, and I'm using a Bluetooth module HC-05 to do it. Now I want to encrypt and decrypt messages (which contain the values of the gas sensor) using an AES library.

That's my code on Arduino IDE:

```
    #include <AES.h>
    #include <AESLib.h>
    #include <AES_config.h>
    #include <xbase64.h>

    #define VCC2 5
    int smokeA0 = A0;
    int buzzer = 11; 

    float sensorValue; 

    void setup() {
    
    pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(smokeA0, INPUT);
    pinMode(VCC2, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(VCC2, HIGH); 
    
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Gas sensor warning up!");
    delay(2000); //allow the sensor to warm up
    noTone(buzzer);
    }

    void loop() {
  
    sensorValue = analogRead(smokeA0); 
  
    Serial.print("Sensor value: ");
    Serial.print(sensorValue);
  
    if(sensorValue > 300){
  
    Serial.print(" | Smoke detected!");
    tone(buzzer,1000,2000); 
    }
    else {
    noTone(buzzer);
    }
    Serial.println("");
    delay(200); //wait 2s for next reading
     }
```

How is the code through which I can encrypt the value sensor? And have I include it to the code above?

In the site file zip containing the informations of the project there's also this file called "Receiver", on Arduino IDE, too:

```
     #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
     #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
     #include <AES.h>

     AES aes ;

     byte key [N_BLOCK] ;

     byte cipher [N_BLOCK] ;
     byte check [N_BLOCK] ;

     #define PIN_EN 6
     #define BUTTON 13

     SoftwareSerial btSerial(4, 5);
     LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

     String msg = "";
     bool isConnected = false;

     String readString = "";
     byte msg_received[16];
     char final_str[16];

     void setup( )
     {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      Serial.print("Receiving Application\n\n");
      lcd.begin(16, 2);
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Receiving App");

      int bits = 128;
      set_bits (bits, key, 0) ;  // all zero key
      byte succ;
      succ = aes.set_key (key, bits) ;
      if (succ != SUCCESS) Serial.println ("Failure set_key") ;
  
      checkConnection();
      if(!isConnected) {
        pinMode(PIN_EN, OUTPUT);  // this pin will pull the HC-010 EN HIGH to switch module to AT mode
        digitalWrite(PIN_EN, HIGH);
        Serial.println("Going in AT mode for BLE HC-10");
        btSerial.begin(38400);
        delay(1000);
        pinMode(A0, INPUT);
        while(!isConnected) {
          if (btSerial.available()) {
            char c = btSerial.read();
            Serial.write(c);         
          }
          if (Serial.available()) {  
            char c = Serial.read();  
            btSerial.write(c);       
          }
          checkConnection();
        } 
    
        btSerial.flush();
        btSerial.end();
        btSerial.begin(9600); 

        digitalWrite(PIN_EN, LOW);
        Serial.println("Exiting from AT mode for BLE HC-10");
      }
    }

    void checkConnection() {
      int x = analogRead(A0);
        if(x > 700) {
          Serial.println("HC-10 is connected");
          isConnected = true;
        }
    }

    void loop( )
    {
      if(isConnected) { 
        getBTReply();
        if(msg.length() > 0) {
          Serial.println("Received msg: " + msg);
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.begin(16, 2);
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("Receiving App");
          lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
          lcd.print("Temp. > ");
          lcd.print(msg);
          lcd.setCursor(13, 1);
          lcd.print(" C");
        } else {
          Serial.println("Received no msg");
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.begin(16, 2);
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("Receiving App");
          lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
          lcd.print("no message received");
        }
      }
      delay(4000);
    }

    void getBTReply() {
      msg = "";
      int i = 0;
      while (btSerial.available()) {
        msg_received[i] = btSerial.read();
        i++;
      }
      if (i==16) {
        byte succ;
        succ = aes.decrypt (msg_received, check) ;
        if (succ != SUCCESS) Serial.println ("Failure decrypt") ;
        String x = prs_byte_hex(check, 128);
        textFromHexString(x.c_str(), final_str);
        msg = String(final_str);
        memset(final_str,0,strlen(final_str));
      }
    }

    void set_bits (int bits, byte * a, int count)
    {
      bits >>= 3 ;
      byte bcount = count >> 3 ;
      for (byte i = 0 ; i < bcount ; i++)
        a [i] = 0xFF ;
      if ((count & 7) != 0)
        a [bcount++] = 0xFF & (0xFF00 >> (count & 7)) ;
      for (byte i = bcount ; i < bits ; i++)
        a [i] = 0x00 ;
    }


    char * hex = "0123456789abcdef" ;


    void print_value (byte * a, int bits)
    {
      bits >>= 3 ;
      for (int i = 0 ; i < bits ; i++)
        {
          byte b = a[i] ;
          // test purpose only
          Serial.print (hex [b >> 4]) ;
          Serial.print (hex [b & 15]) ;
        }
      Serial.println () ;
    }

    String prs_byte_hex (byte * a, int bits)
    {
      bits >>= 3 ;
      String str_toparse;
      for (int i = 0 ; i < bits ; i++)
        {
          byte b = a[i] ;
          str_toparse += hex [b >> 4];
          str_toparse += hex [b & 15];
        }
      return str_toparse;
    }

    void textFromHexString(char *hex, char *result)
    {
    char temp[3];
    int index = 0;

    temp[2] = '\0';
    while (hex[index])
    {
        strncpy(temp, &hex[index], 2);
        *result = (char)strtol(temp, NULL, 16);
        result++;
        index += 2;
    }
    *result = '\0';
    }
```

So I don't need to build a Web Server in VSC to establish a connection through two devices?
If yes, can you please share me the code?
Sorry, I'm not very practical in IoT and I'm completely alone to do the project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending data using the HC-05 to another arduino, then here is how to encrypt the data:

```
uint8_t key[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
char data[] = "0123456789012345"; //16 chars == 16 bytes - Your data you want to send
aes128_enc_single(key, data);
```

Then on the receiving arduino

```
aes128_dec_single(key, data);
```

You send that data using serial. The receiving Arduino would also need an HC-05 module, or if you're sending to your computer, you can use a USB bluetooth adapter. You don't need a webserver to establish a connection between 2 arduinos, no. If you're sending data online, then you'll need to have a way to connect to the internet from one of your devices.

Comment: I'd like to send data using the HC-05 to my PC, not to another Arduino. Is it possible? 
I am powering the arduino with a power outlet and i connected the pc and arduino via bluetooth with the hc-05. Now what I want to do is to create a very simple app which receives the encrypted values of the sensor, decrypts them and displays the value of the smoke sensor. Is it possible to do it with only HC-05 and one Arduino?

Comment: You connected the HC-05 to the PC, are you getting any data? Did you figure that part out? You are being very vague about what you have done so far. At least get data going over serial to the pc first before encrypting it. Open a serial monitor on the pc and set to the Bluetooth serial port.